# my file manager uninstalled accidentally

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, apk

i have xolo a500s jellybean version cellphone...i give root access... and by accidentally my file manager uninstalled... and i have a backup apk of my file manager...i try to install it but after some install processing it says “×app not installed",i need my file manager back...and i don't like and don't want to use other file explorers so please give me suggestion what can i do for it..??
:-(

Comment: What do you mean backup .apk? Is it the base.apk?

Comment: Place your apk under /system/app, reboot and then tell us the result.

Answer (score 1):

This file manager app is a system app thus you will not be able to install it as a user app (using the default package installer) due to extra permissions that can be granted only for system apps.

To fix this you need to push that app to `system/app` using one of the methods below :

## 1. ES File Explorer (or any other root explorer):

- Install [ES File explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) from the Google Play Store
- Open it and swipe right to open the left panel containing the the settings list.

  - Scroll down and toggle root explorer
  - Grant root access then click on `root explorer` item.
- You will be prompt with a set of settings. Locate system and choose `rw` (`rw` stands for read/write)
- Locate your backed up apk file and make sure the file name contains no special characters or spaces.
- Long tap on the apk file. The file will be selected. Now click on the copy icon in the top bar.
- Navigate to `/system/app` and paste the apk file.
- Reboot your phone the file explorer will be installed

## 2. ADB (root and a computer needed )

- Make sure `adb` debugging is on under settings >> developer settings
- On your computerm make sure you have `adb` in your path and drivers are installed if you are using windows or `udev rules` if you're using Linux. `adb` works out of the box for OSX.
- Plug your phone to the pc and copy the backed up apk to your pc (in the example I will assume you put the apk under `c:\myApk.apk`
- Fire up a command line/terminal and type the following commands.

Make sure your phone is unlocked

```
adb kill-server
adb remount
adb push c:\myApk.apk /system/app/fileExplorerStock.apk
adb reboot
```

After the phone reboots the apk should be installed